# Drawable not displayed

Tags: java, android, drawable

Why `mImage` is not displayed?

```
public class Manager extends Thread{
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private boolean mRunning;



public Drawable mImage;
public Manager(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context){

     mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
     mRunning = false;

     Resources res = context.getResources();


         mImage = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.nhero2);


  public void setRunning(boolean running)
   {
       mRunning = running;
   }

   public void run()
   {
       while (mRunning)
       {
           Canvas canvas = null;
           try
           {
               // подготовка Canvas-а
               canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
               synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
               {
                   // собственно рисование
                   //doDraw(canvas);
                   mImage.draw(canvas);
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e) { }
           finally
           {
               if (canvas != null)
               {
                   mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

P.S. sorry 4 my english

P.P.S.
i trying to create my own scrool shooter hah
full code here(sry for bad comments)
class Manager http://pastebin.com/Sjd57uqT
class View and class scrolBckgr http://pastebin.com/A5u5UJea

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740687/add-image-to-surface-view-in-android

Comment: Lalit Poptani, thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call mImage.setBounds(...); otherwise the canvas doesn't know where to draw the Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem you have is that as soon as you start the thread with `.start();` the boolean `mRunning` is false and the thread will finish immediately. When you try to call `.setRunning(true);` after the thread has started it won't have any effect because the thread already finished.

Comment: thx, but i don't think so - actually `doDraw()` is works if i repacle commentary sings

Comment: i tryed to set `mRunning = true;` in constructor too but nothing had changed

Comment: ok, well threading is always difficult with drawing. You could try to call the invalidate() method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate() and otherwise read this blog post http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html