# displaying images on surfaceView of android app but on a particular place on the surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview

Really need an answer to this. 
So i have a relative view and in that a surface view. I managed to get the camera's preview in my activity. However now i want a few small images on surfaceview in different locations/places on the surfaceview and the locations of the images will keep changing on surfacechanged. So questions:

How to get images on a specific loaction on my surface view. ok drawable, get image from res but after that?
and if that happens then i can prolly call it from surfacechanged and it will update but what function do i use for the above question

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7744696/931277. Note particularly the `onDraw` method of `mySurfaceView`.

Comment: use texture concept inn opengl es2.0..