# SurfaceView won't draw while under image view

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, surfaceview

I have a function that will keep on drawing on the surfaceView to simulate the animation of a character on the surfaceView. But after adding a imageView on top of the SurfaceView, the SurfaceView stop drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setZOrderOnTop(true)` you have added in the `surfaceview` init. 
because `surfaceview` should be always on top to draw anything,

Although after that you can't put image on top of that, for that you can use other question ref
[add image to surface view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740687/add-image-to-surface-view-in-android)

for that. let me know if that helps